# MYSQL select query with count condition and join

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know the difference between below queries. Both returns the same value. I have idea about INNER JOIN and but i can't understand how first query returns the same value.

```
SELECT  *
FROM 
  `products`
WHERE
  (
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM `categories`
    WHERE `products`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id` AND `slug` = 'aprons'
  ) >= 1 
  AND `slug` <> 'products-1'
```

---

```
SELECT products.* 
FROM 
  products
  INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = products.category_id
WHERE 
  products.slug <> 'products-1'
  AND categories.slug = 'aprons'
```

Comment: That first query almost assuredly does not do what you intend. The subquery return value isn't altering the returned rows of products but is more of an on/off switch. (p.s. thanks for the code reformat @Michael)

Comment: The first query is doing a sub-query to see if any category in the resulting set has a slug of "aprons," and only returning those values (sans-"products-1").   The second is doing the same filter, but as a whole, only taking records that relate to the categories table and don't have a slug of "aprons."  Essentially, they're doing the same filter, but different ways.  But the `INNER JOIN` query is far more perfomant, as it doesn't have to run a sub-query for every record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second query is more efficient. and have use inner join . first one is used a sub query. sub query is not necessary to verify to categories  existence. same result are displayed but on point of optimisation second query is more efficient.

when thinking the first query

(
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM `categories`
    WHERE `products`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id` AND `slug` = 'aprons'
  ) >= 1

this part is execute for every single products record . simply categories is iterated for every single record in products table.

Answer (score -1):

The first query will be more efficient since the tables will not need to be joined. You may not have noticed a big difference in execution time, but if the tables were much larger, you would have noticed that the first query returned much faster.

An Inner Join will combine the two tables based on the rows that have values in both tables. In other words, there will not be any null values in the resulting table.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to disagree with your first point that it's more efficient to use a sub-query for *every* record, over using a `JOIN`, which a) doesn't have to iterate over every single record in that manner, and b) is optimized to hell and back, as that's *exactly* what it was intended to do.

Comment: I suppose I should have done a bit more research before readily answering. However, in my experience with Oracle, I have noticed that on large, unsorted, unfiltered tables, sub-queries usually win out.

Comment: I am in confuse when execute the first query because I execute the sub-query alone and returned value as 3. Then i replaced the returned value to the place of sub query. But the result was different from the old query.

Comment: @KalpaPerera It's because that query is being run for every record in the resultset.  You won't get the same results by replacing the sub-query with the result of one of the records.